# Pop Up in Behind (Not z-index) and how to function close popup in link

Tags: javascript, php, popup

i create popup javascript, for show school. But when i click link show popup, this popup position in behind, i already add z-index in css inline but does not work :'(

This is screenshot
[image]

This is my script..

```
 <html>
<?php include "connection.php";?>
    <script>
    function profile(kode,logo,address,ket,name,status,phone)
    {
    var data =''+kode+'';
    var h ='';
    h +='<div style="background-color:#ffffff; z-index:9999999;" id="profilenya" >';
    h +='<div style="background-color:#ffffff; z-index:9999999;">';
    h +='<br/><h2 style="background-color:#359ace; width: auto;"><center>'+name+'</center></h2><br/>';
    h +='<table><tr><td rowspan="2">&nbsp;  <img  style="border:1px solid #369ace; padding: 5px 30px;"  width="160px" height="160px" src="images/sekolah/logo/'+logo+'"></td>';

    h +='<td>&nbsp; &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i> <font color="black">'+address+'</td>';
    h +='<tr><td>&nbsp; &nbsp;  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i> <font color="black">'+phone+'</td></tr>';
    h +='<tr height="20px"><td></td><td></td></tr>';
    h +='<tr><td><center style="border:1px solid #369ace; padding: 5px 3px;"  >Klik Disini untuk mendukung <br/>agar sekolah ini menampilkan <br/>brosur online</center> &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>';
    h +='<td><div style="border-radius: 3px; border:1px solid #369ace; padding: 5px 3px;">  <font color="black">Ket: <br/>  &nbsp;'+ket+' </div></td></tr>';
    h +='<tr height="10px"><td></td><td></td></tr>';
    h +='</table>';
    h +='<a href="#" id="closedialog" style="display:block; position:absolute; top:3px; right:2px; background:rgb(245,245,245); color:black; height:30px; width:35px; font-size:30px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&times;</a>';


    h +='</div>';
    h +='</div>';
    $('body').append(h);
    $('#profilenya').dialog({
    resizable: true,
    width: 420,
    height: 300,
    position: {
    my: 'center',
    at: 'center',
    of: window
    },
    modal: true
    });
    }
    </script>   

    <?php 
    $data_school=mysql_query("select * from school");
    $i=0;
    while($school = mysql_fetch_object($data_school))
    {
    $i++
    echo "".$i."<a onclick=\"profile('".$row['kode']."','".$row['logo']."','".$row['address']."','".$row['ket']."','".$row['name']."','".$row['status']."','".$row['phone']."');\" ><h4>".$row['name']."</h4></a>";
    }
    ?>  
                </html>
```

And how to close popup in link (X). This code..

```
h +='<a href="#" id="closedialog" style="display:block; position:absolute; top:3px; right:2px; background:rgb(245,245,245); color:black; height:30px; width:35px; font-size:30px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&times;</a>';
```

Help me.. pliss

Comment: Does this just have to be a custom alert box?

Comment: yes.. like alert box 
but i custom it..

Comment: Build the custom alert box in your HTML, add the CSS in a separate CSS file and then simply with your javascript *show it* - like change `display: none; ` to `display: block;` or use `opacity`. What I mean is don't use javascript to literally write your html for you. Otherwise it has to recreate the element every time it's made. Have it ready in html (that means it gets loaded when the page loads) and just make it visible with the help of javascript.

Comment: As for the  `&times;` - simply have clicking that link call a javascript function which adds the CSS class `display: none;` back to the alert box's div! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a very basic [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5q5f35gb/) of the things I explained in the comments:

- Have your 'popup' or alert ready as an HTML element
- Hide it using CSS
- Use your Javascript simply to show/rehide it by adding and removing CSS classes

The HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <button type="button" id="clck" onclick="javascript:popup();">Clicky?</button>
</div>


<div id="alertContainer">
    <div id="alertContent">
        <p>
            I fight dragons with tooth picks. Rawrr!
        </p>        
        <span id="close">&times;</span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

And Javascript:

```
var popupBox = document.getElementById('alertContainer');
var x = document.getElementById('close');

function popup(){    
    popupBox.className = popupBox.className + 'show';
}   



$('#close').click(function() {
    popupBox.className = "";
});
```

There's also plugins like [SweetAlert](http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert) available.

**ps** I didn't use pure javascript - the close buttons click is with jQuery (so you'd have to import that in your HTML file's header)